# Elements Will Not Cover Whole Screen Despite height:100%

Tags: html, css

I am a website and I have two images side by side that are links to other pages. For these two images, want them both to cover the whole screen (except for the nav bar at the top). I have tried to make height: 100% for multiple elements, but it doesn't change anything.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">
        <div class="content-row">
            <div class="content-container">
                <a href="theteam.html">
                    <img src="assets/team-photo.JPG">
                    <p class="center">The Team</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content-container">
                <img src="assets/test.JPG">
                <p class="center">The Vehicle</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}

html, body {
font-family:futura;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:(25,28,31);
}

.content-row {
display: flex;
max-height: auto;
}

.content-container {
width: 50%;
position: relative;
}

.content-container img {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
-webkit-transition: 0.75s ;
-moz-transition: 0.75s ;
-ms-transition: 0.75s ;
-o-transition: 0.75s ;
transition: 0.75s ; 
}

.content-container .center {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin: 0;
font-size: 400%;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0);
-webkit-transition: border 0.75s ease;
-moz-transition: border 0.75s ease;
-ms-transition: border 0.75s ease;
-o-transition: border 0.75s ease;
transition: border 0.75s ease; 
}

.content-container:hover img {
animation-name: darken;
animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-duration: 0.75s;
filter: brightness(55%);
}

.content-container:hover .center {
border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255, 1);
}

@keyframes darken {
from {filter: brightness(100%);}
to {filter: brightness(55%);}
}
```

Any recommendations either minor or drastic help. I am a novice and this seems to be out of my realm, so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simpliest solution

Use `100vh`.

```
.content-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* instead of 100%;*/
}
```

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: futura;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: (25, 28, 31);
}

.content-row {
  display: flex;
  max-height: auto;
}

.content-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.content-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* instead of 100% */
  -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
  -moz-transition: 0.75s;
  -ms-transition: 0.75s;
  -o-transition: 0.75s;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.content-container .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -moz-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -ms-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -o-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  transition: border 0.75s ease;
}

.content-container:hover img {
  animation-name: darken;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  filter: brightness(55%);
}

.content-container:hover .center {
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@keyframes darken {
  from {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  to {
    filter: brightness(55%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="body">
    <div class="content-row">
      <div class="content-container">
        <a href="theteam.html">
          <img src="assets/team-photo.JPG">
          <p class="center">The Team</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <img src="assets/test.JPG">
        <p class="center">The Vehicle</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info:

- [Some info](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).
- [Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).
- [CanIUse?](https://caniuse.com/#search=viewport%20units)

## More annoying way...

you must put `height: 100%` on every element, from `html` to the `img`, which looks like this:

```
#container,
#body,
.content-row,
.content-container,
.content-container > a {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
#container,
#body,
.content-row,
.content-container,
.content-container>a {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: futura;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: (25, 28, 31);
}

.content-row {
  display: flex;
  max-height: auto;
}

.content-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.content-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
  -moz-transition: 0.75s;
  -ms-transition: 0.75s;
  -o-transition: 0.75s;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.content-container .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -moz-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -ms-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  -o-transition: border 0.75s ease;
  transition: border 0.75s ease;
}

.content-container:hover img {
  animation-name: darken;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  filter: brightness(55%);
}

.content-container:hover .center {
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@keyframes darken {
  from {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  to {
    filter: brightness(55%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="body">
    <div class="content-row">
      <div class="content-container">
        <a href="theteam.html">
          <img src="assets/team-photo.JPG">
          <p class="center">The Team</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <img src="assets/test.JPG">
        <p class="center">The Vehicle</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: I highly recommend using the following code so that the borders do not exceed the screen.:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top; /* For the <a> tags */
}
```

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)